# Parsing unique words from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a project to parse out unique words from a large number of text files.  I've got the file handling down, but I'm trying to refine the parsing procedure.  Each file has a specific text segment that ends with certain phrases that I'm catching with a regex on my live system.

The parser should walk through each line, and check each word against 3 criteria:

1. Longer than two characters
2. Not in a predefined dictionary set `dict_file`
3. Not already in the word list

The result should be a 2D array, each row a list of unique words per file, which is written to a CSV file using the `.writerow(foo)` method after each file is processed.

My working code's below, but it's slow and kludgy, what am I missing?

My production system is running 2.5.1 with just the default modules (so NLTK is a no-go), can't be upgraded to 2.7+.

```
def process(line):
    line_strip = line.strip()
    return line_strip.translate(punct, string.punctuation)

# Directory walking and initialization here
report_set = set()
with open(fullpath, 'r') as report:
    for line in report:
        # Strip out the CR/LF and punctuation from the input line
        line_check = process(line)
        if line_check == "FOOTNOTES":
            break
        for word in line_check.split():
            word_check = word.lower()
            if ((word_check not in report_set) and (word_check not in dict_file) 
                 and (len(word) > 2)):
                report_set.append(word_check)
report_list = list(report_set)
```

Edit:  Updated my code based on steveha's recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that an `in` test for a `list` is slow.  You should probably keep a `set` to keep track of what words you have seen, because the `in` test for a `set` is very fast.

Example:

```
report_set = set()
for line in report:
    for word in line.split():
        if we_want_to_keep_word(word):
            report_set.add(word)
```

Then when you are done:
    report_list = list(report_set)

Anytime you need to force a `set` into a `list`, you can.  But if you just need to loop over it or do `in` tests, you can leave it as a `set`; it's legal to do `for x in report_set:`

Another problem that might or might not matter is that you are slurping all the lines from the file in one go, using the `.readlines()` method.  For really large files it is better to just use the open file-handle object as an iterator, like so:

```
with open("filename", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ... # process each line here
```

A big problem is that I don't even see how this code can work:

```
while 1:
    lines = report.readlines()
    if not lines:
        break
```

This will loop forever.  The first statement slurps all input lines with `.readlines()`, then we loop again, then the next call to `.readlines()` has `report` already exhausted, so the call to `.readlines()` returns an empty list, which breaks out of the infinite loop.  But this has now lost all the lines we just read, and the rest of the code must make do with an empty `lines` variable.  How does this even work?

So, get rid of that whole `while 1` loop, and change the next loop to `for line in report:`.

Also, you don't really need to keep a `count` variable.  You can use `len(report_set)` at any time to find out how many words are in the `set`.

Also, with a `set` you don't actually need to check whether a word is `in` the set; you can just always call `report_set.add(word)` and if it's already in the `set` it won't be added again!

Also, you don't *have* to do it my way, but I like to make a generator that does all the processing.  Strip the line, translate the line, split on whitespace, and yield up words ready to use.  I would also force the words to lower-case except I don't know whether it's important that `FOOTNOTES` be detected only in upper-case.

So, put all the above together and you get:

```
def words(file_object):
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.strip().translate(None, string.punctuation)
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

report_set = set()
with open(fullpath, 'r') as report:
    for word in words(report):
        if word == "FOOTNOTES":
            break
        word = word.lower()
        if len(word) > 2 and word not in dict_file:
            report_set.add(word)

print("Words in report_set: %d" % len(report_set))
```

Comment: So use `set.add(foo)` rather than `list.append(foo)`?

Comment: The reason I have the `while ` loop (which should be `True` rather than 1) is to catch just the portion of text that I'm interested that's delimited - that way I only ingest the text that I want, and not the superfluous stuff that surrounds it (mostly metadata that I'm not interested in).

Comment: But I don't understand how it can work.  `.readlines()` will read all the lines there are, and exhaust the open file-handle object; then the second pass through the loop throws away all the lines before breaking out of the infinite loop.  How does that do anything useful?  If you are using it and it works, can you please tell me why it works?  Do you have some extra test in your real code that can break out of the infinite loop before all input lines are thrown away?

Comment: I think I'm getting there - pulled the `while` loop and the `readlines()` out.  I like abstracting out `words` into a function, will have to play with that.

Comment: The `while` loop kludge I got from [link](http://effbot.org/zone/readline-performance.htm), which seems to be a tad dated.  If I'm reading it right, it works by checking for a zero-length line (effectively the EOF).

Comment: I analyzed what that `while 1:` loop does once in my answer and once again in these comments.  I am not going to do it a third time.  I do not understand how it can possibly work, and when I tested it, it did exactly what I predicted (set `lines` to an empty list).  It's moot now anyway since you removed it.

Comment: I can't really explain it either - thank you very much, by the way, for your help!  I'd give you bonus karma if I could.

Comment: You're welcome!  :-)  I really love Python and it's fun for me to help people with good problems like this one.

Comment: The `while` loop from http://effbot.org/zone/readline-performance.htm has a line that says `pass # do something` and that is the important bit.  That was a stand-in for actual code that would actually do something.  Since what you posted here originally didn't have any code at that point, the loop had the effect I said (of just setting `lines` to an empty list).

Comment: Thank you to @tbc0 for editing the answer to improve it.  By the way, you can always find documentation for older versions of Python on the python.org web site.  Here is a direct link to the documentation that explains `str.translate()` for 2.5:  http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/string-methods.html

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing report_list with a dictionary or set. 
word_check not in report_list works slow if report_list is a list